# How to pivot this particular query

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, pivot

Given the Script/Data

```
CREATE TABLE #DemoData
(
    Name varchar(50),
    Billing money,
    Comission money,
    Month varchar(10)
)

insert into #DemoData
VALUES ('Lílian Araújo Albernaz',4308.00,1271.60,'August'),
('Lílian Araújo Albernaz',3254.00,898.75,'December'),
('Lílian Araújo Albernaz',5792.00,1711.89,'July'),
('Lílian Araújo Albernaz',6062.50,1626.18,'November'),
('Lílian Araújo Albernaz',6681.00,1893.06,'October'),
('Lílian Araújo Albernaz',6102.00,1796.34,'September'),
('Leicy Araujo Albernaz',2668.00,2114.92,'August'),
('Leicy Araujo Albernaz',1200.00,950.33,'December'),
('Leicy Araujo Albernaz',3152.50,2498.87,'July'),
('Leicy Araujo Albernaz',2558.00,2030.05,'November'),
('Leicy Araujo Albernaz',2845.00,2251.37,'October'),
('Leicy Araujo Albernaz',3050.00,2417.33,'September'),
('Núbia Nicacio Brito',2309.00,1828.60,'August'),
('Núbia Nicacio Brito',1050.00,828.39,'December'),
('Núbia Nicacio Brito',1977.50,1564.32,'July'),
('Núbia Nicacio Brito',1995.00,1577.34,'November'),
('Núbia Nicacio Brito',2414.00,1908.87,'October'),
('Núbia Nicacio Brito',2575.00,2034.45,'September'),
('Sonia Caxeta',1507.00,1188.02,'August'),
('Sonia Caxeta',900.00,706.99,'December'),
('Sonia Caxeta',1988.00,1571.72,'July'),
('Sonia Caxeta',1655.00,1304.71,'November'),
('Sonia Caxeta',1857.00,1463.44,'October'),
('Sonia Caxeta',2013.00,1587.93,'September'),
('Mirian Pinto Rabelo',1020.00,454.67,'August'),
('Mirian Pinto Rabelo',800.00,359.84,'December'),
('Mirian Pinto Rabelo',1135.00,518.28,'July'),
('Mirian Pinto Rabelo',1000.00,443.42,'November'),
('Mirian Pinto Rabelo',2020.00,911.13,'October'),
('Mirian Pinto Rabelo',1415.00,625.48,'September'),
('Cleuza',2683.00,1277.25,'August'),
('Cleuza',1530.00,688.70,'December'),
('Cleuza',2012.00,984.47,'July'),
('Cleuza',2790.00,1311.74,'November'),
('Cleuza',2298.00,1099.48,'October'),
('Cleuza',2160.00,1048.80,'September'),
('Nivia Santos Caldeira Alves',80.00,38.97,'October'),
('Thais Pereira da Cruz',449.00,357.43,'December'),
('Thais Pereira da Cruz',227.00,179.02,'November'),
('Geisiane Araujo Amparo',305.00,145.03,'December')
```

how can I pivot this table so I get:

```
NAME   | Month 1 | Month 2 | ... | Month N
Lilian    100       200              300
Janeth    10        NULL             NULL
Dorias    300       200              NULL
```

EG: I get one line for Billing and one line for commission...

PS: Given time sensitivity, I can do with 2 queries, one for billing and another for commission

**EDIT1**
The query I have so far:

```
DECLARE @cols AS NVARCHAR(MAX),
@query  AS NVARCHAR(MAX)

select @cols = STUFF((SELECT distinct ',' + QUOTENAME(MES)
                from #DemoData
        FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
        ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') 
    ,1,1,'')

set @query = 'SELECT Name,' + @cols + ' 
        from 
        #DemoData AS p
        pivot 
        (
            SUM(p.Billing)
            for p.Month in (' + @cols + ')
        ) AS p'
        --GROUP BY Name,'+@cols

 execute sp_executesql @query;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a quick pivot for billing.  (It would be a small matter to make it dynamic and have both billing and commission as columns or even rows)

```
Select [Name],[Month 01],[Month 02],[Month 03],[Month 04],[Month 05],[Month 06],[Month 07],[Month 08],[Month 09],[Month 10],[Month 11],[Month 12]
  From (
        Select [Name],[Billing],[Col] = Format(MM,'Month 00')
         From  #DemoData A
         Join (Select * From (Values(1,'January'),(2,'February'),(3,'March'),(4,'April'),(5,'May'),(6,'June'),(7,'July'),(8,'August'),(9,'September'),(10,'October'),(11,'November'),(12,'December')) Mths(MM,MMMM)) B
           on  A.Month=B.MMMM
       ) A
 Pivot (Sum([Billing]) For [Col] in ([Month 01],[Month 02],[Month 03],[Month 04],[Month 05],[Month 06],[Month 07],[Month 08],[Month 09],[Month 10],[Month 11],[Month 12]) ) p
```

Returns

[image]

EDIT - Dynamic Version

```
Declare @SQL varchar(max) = Stuff((Select Distinct ',' + QuoteName(Col) 
                                    From (Select Distinct [Col] = Format(MM,'Month 00')
                                          From   #DemoData A
                                          Join (Select * From (Values(1,'January'),(2,'February'),(3,'March'),(4,'April'),(5,'May'),(6,'June'),(7,'July'),(8,'August'),(9,'September'),(10,'October'),(11,'November'),(12,'December')) Mths(MM,MMMM)) B
                                          on A.Month = B.MMMM  
                                         ) A Order by 1 For XML Path('')),1,1,'') 
Select  @SQL = '
 Select [Name],' + @SQL + '
  From (
        Select [Name],[Billing],[Col] = Format(MM,''Month 00'')
         From  #DemoData A
         Join (Select * From (Values(1,''January''),(2,''February''),(3,''March''),(4,''April''),(5,''May''),(6,''June''),(7,''July''),(8,''August''),(9,''September''),(10,''October''),(11,''November''),(12,''December'')) Mths(MM,MMMM)) B
           on  A.Month=B.MMMM
       ) A
 Pivot (Sum([Billing]) For [Col] in (' + @SQL + ') ) p'
Exec(@SQL);
```

Returns

[image]

Comment: i'll try to adjust! let me check it... I don't get the join part... can you elaborate that part?

Comment: @Leonardo As you can see the JOIN creates a table of month names and numbers.   Since your data has month name, I assumed you wanted to keep them in order (not alphabetical)

Comment: Yes I do... pls check my edit with the query I'm using right now

Comment: @Leonardo Let me know if you want all 12 months to be displayed, or only those in your data

Comment: this way is great! I just want to know why your query returns a single line per person, and mine returns multiple now...

Comment: @Leonardo Same data?  If so, I have no idea.

Comment: @Leonardo Did you add any fields the SQL?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/130722/discussion-between-leonardo-and-john-cappelletti).